# Testing spring-cloud-dataflow stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking for a way to easily test any flow. And I thing that spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests could help me to do that but I can'f find any documentation about that.

How does it work? I launched the application but I don't know how can write and run test.

Does anyone has any suggestion about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests  is used to deploy and run test scenarios. The readme has an extensive example on how to bootstrap it, is your question about how to write a test for a stream app, or how to test a deployed stream end to end?